# How to run multiple boot2docker with docker-machine?

Tags: ssh, docker, ubuntu-14.04, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine on Ubuntu 14.04. I have a VM with boot2docker running made by following command

```
 `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev `
```

I am trying to create another VM by following

```
`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url /home/<user name>/Downloads/rancheros.iso rancher`
```

It runs , gives the message

```
`Waiting for VM to start`
```

then

```
 `docker@localhost's password:`
```

waiting for the password.

I tried password `tcuser`( saw it on #405 on github) to no avail.

for VM dev : Boot2Docker version 1.6.2, build master : 4534e65